# Why does heroku search in the app/build/index.js folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, heroku

I have the problem that Heroku searches in the folder app/build/index.js for my index.js but this is wrong. That is why I get this error: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJP2g.png)

My folder structure looks like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPVLp.png)

My package.json:

```
"name": "market-research-tool",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "./build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./build/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.16",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.13"
  }
}
```

My Procfile:

```
web: node ./build/index.js
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That's correct and expected behavior. When you deploy on Heroku it puts everything into the folder `/app`. You are executing `./build/*.js` which resolves to `/app/build/*.js`. Your problem is at the building step. The content in `/app/build/` isn't generated properly.

Comment: Do you think that the build folder is not created at all? Should I include this command in the package.json : "postinstall": "npm run build"?

Comment: I can't tell. Create another fresh copy of your project locally and note down all the commands you are running. Then adjust your `package.json`. In the end you should be able to run your project with `git clone yourproject`, `cd yourproject`, `npm install`,  `npm build`, `npm start`.